# How to encode raw URL string for sending a request

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to send a request by

```
request_url = "http://localhost:8005/materials/start_date=2012-01-29&end_date=2013-03-29&table_name=Unemployment  rate + emplyment rate&measure=All"

requests.get(request_url)
```

However I didn't get anything from the request in Python, but I can get the expected response via browser, I think it is the escape string problem, how to do it in the right way ?

### Update

I tried the following method, but the result is not equal to `http://localhost:8005//materials/start_date=2012-01-29&end_date=2013-03-29&table_name=Unemployment%20rate`

```
    p = {
        "start_date": start_date,
        "end_date": end_date,
        "table_name": table_name
    }
    req = requests.get(request_url, params=p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a dictionary as the `params` for `requests.get` and let the library handle building the parameters, eg:

```
request_url = "http://localhost:8005/materials/"
requests.get(request_url, params={
    'start_date': '2012-01-29',
    'end_date': '2013-03-29',
    # etc....
    }
)
```

If the server's adamant it's not going to accept `?` like it should, then:

```
from urllib import urlencode
requests.get(request_url + urlencode({
    'start_date': '2012-01-29',
    'end_date': '2913-03-29'})
)
```

Comment: Hi, THanks for your reply, but the method is not identical to `http://localhost:8005//materials/start_date=2012-01-29&end_date=2013-03-29&table_name=Unemployment%20rate` http get method

Comment: So the server isn't expecting a proper `?key1=value1&key2=value2` formatted query params then? It's actually expecting that as part of the path!?

Comment: Hi Can I remove the leading `?` question mark, the server doesn't expect it.

Comment: @user3675188 I've updated the answer to include using `urlencode` which will do the escaping and provide a string without a leading `?`